# Looking for a "Bikur Cholim" behavior manual

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, choleh-sick

Several years ago, while my kids were in elementary school, I think they came home with a "Bikur Cholim" behavior guide. It was designed mainly for kids, but certainly can apply to adults.

The guide began with an overview of the mitzvah of *Bikur Cholim* (visiting the infirmed / homebound) and then listed some behavior guidelines such as:

- When / how often to visit
- What to o rnot to bring as a gift
- How to behave in the room
- How long to stay

and other useful advice and tips. The guide covered hospital, home, and nursing home environments.

I couldn't find anything like this on-line. Does anyone know of anything downloadable on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [*The Mitzvah of Bikur Cholim*](http://www.thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol10Issue9.pdf) and [*The Mitzvah of Bikur Cholim Part 2*](http://www.thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol10Issue10.pdf).

Comment: This seems better than the one I recall my kids bringing. Thanks for the links. I esp. appreciate the brownie advertisement at the end of part 1. I'm hungry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try the [Training Manual For Bikur Cholim Volunteers](http://www.bikurcholimcc.org/BCStudentManualJan10.pdf)  put out by 
The Rabbi Isaac N. Trainin Bikur Cholim Coordinating Council, http://www.bikurcholimcc.org/.